# Update query in mysql not the same result in mssql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I change my database (MySQL to SQL Server) and now i have problem in
   update query. When i update in MySQL with the same data it return '0
   affected row' and I try to do the same in SQL Server but it return 1
   affected row.

---

```
UPDATE stud_details 
set stud_fname = 'SHERWIN'
WHERE stud_lrn = 20170610000
```

Help me about the query for SQL Server that will return 0 when you update same data

Comment: The statement is very basic and fully standard compliant. It updates all ros where `stud_lrn = 20170610000`. The datatype for `stud_lrn` should of course be an integer type, i.e. `BIGINT` or `DECIMAL(n,0)`. Try `SELECT * FROM stud_details WHERE stud_lrn = 20170610000` to see what rows match the condition.

Comment: Does the record exist in both databases?

Comment: @Thorsten When i try the query you said "stud_fname = SHERWN"' and when i update the stud_fname and set it to "SHERWIN" . It will return 1 affected row even the value didnt changed unlike in MySQL

Comment: @Peter Yes. But they return different value

Comment: So there is one matching row in each database, but when you look at the data after processing your update, in MySQL the value changed, and in SQL Server it didn't? Maybe you forgot to commit your update? It may be that MySQL is set to auto commit and SQL Server is not. I suggest to never use auto commit and always end an update with an explicit `COMMIT`.

Comment: I try to use `COMMIT` in SQL Server. But it say `(1 row(s) affected)`. Thank you for response i will find query

Answer (score 0):

Sql server is telling you 1 row was affected, because 1 row was updated. If you want to cheat and have 0 rows affected instead, you can do it this way:

```
set nocount on

UPDATE stud_details 
set stud_fname = 'SHERWIN'
WHERE stud_lrn = 20170610000

set nocount off

UPDATE stud_details 
set stud_fname = stud_fname
WHERE 1=2
```

for your first query you wont see the rows affected the second query will have 0 rows affected.

Comment: It works. Thanks! But if i set `nocount on` the return value is always 0. Im using the return value to use ` if else condition ` in my app